# Remove Wordpress'/Woocommerce's wc-blocks-style

Tags: php, css, wordpress, optimization, woocommerce

This is the css I'm trying to remove (image from Google Page Speed Insights). I put this in my `functions.php` file but I'm still getting the same result when I rerun Google Page Speed Insights

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'remove_block_css', 9999999999999999 );
function remove_block_css() {
    wp_dequeue_style( 'wc-blocks-style' ); // WooCommerce
}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe you have a cache?

Comment: @HowardE I clear cache every time before I run pagespeeds